# Modify a legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Good afternoon everyone,
I have a question about ggplot2.

Here is a simplified version of my problem
I have a graphic with four lines with a color for each line.

My code is :

```
 library(ggplot2)
 df=data.frame(x=1:20,
              y=rep(1:5,4),
              ind=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5),rep(4,5))
)

p=ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x,y=y,group=ind, colour=factor(ind))) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(name="",
                      values=c("blue4","green4","blue3","green3"), 
                      labels=c("type1","type1","type2","type2"), 
                      breaks=c("1","3","2","4"))
```

However the blue lines and the green lines stand for a same characteristic, so I would like a legend with only two boxes instead of four : one referring to the blue lines, and the other one reffering to the green lines.
The following code shows you a graphic with the kind of legend I want :

```
plot(x=1:5, y=1:5, col="blue4", type="l", xlim=c(0,20))
lines(x=6:10, y=1:5, col="green4")
lines(x=11:15, y=1:5, col="blue3")
lines(x=16:20, y=1:5, col="green3")
legend("topright", legend=c("type1","type2"), col=c("blue3","green3"), lty=c(1,1))
```

You might say that I should do it the classic way (i.e not using ggplot2), nevertheless my real case is more technically advanced, hence I really need to use ggplot2 (in order to control  more easily other graphic parameters).

I'm sorry if you can't see my graphics. My inteded to post them but I can't due to not enough reputation point 
Thanks in advance if you can help me.
Maël

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new factor with two levels (instead of four) and use this factor as argument for the `colour` parameter in the plot.

The new factor `ind2` has the label `type1` where `ind` is odd and `type2` where `ind` is even.

```
df$ind2 <- factor(!df$ind %% 2, labels = c("type1", "type2"))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = ind, colour = ind2)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue4", "green4"))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer Sven.

However, I really want the two green colors and the two blue colors to be different on my plot.

I chose "green3", "green4", "blue3" and "blue4" because I was in a hurry. But the real colors would be "green1" and "green4", and "blue1" and "blue4".
Besides, in reality my green plots are very close. Same thing for my blue plots. So I want 4 different colors on my graphic, but I would like to have only two colors in my legend.

My main purpose is that my readers can see that my two green plots stands for the same thing, although they are different plots.